# EasyMock - CreateNiceMock

Tags: easymock

A fairly straightforward question regarding EasyMock. Read up a bunch of resources but not sure what I am missing:

The following snippet is creating a unit test using Test-ng:

```
@Test(groups = "unit")
public class SchoolTestEasyMock {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        School mockSchool = EasyMock.createNiceMock(School.class);
        EasyMock.replay(mockSchool);
        System.out.println(mockSchool.getSchoolNumber());
    }
}
```

Let's assume the School class has a simple getter 'getSchoolNumber' that returns an Integer.

The snippet above is printing a 'null' to the console. Since I'm creating a 'nice' mock shouldn't the 'getSchoolNumber' return a default value of 0? Am I missing something while creating the nice mock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html):

> If you would like a "nice" Mock Object that by default allows all method calls and returns appropriate empty values (0, null or false), use niceMock() instead.

As `Integer` is an object, the default value is `null`. 
If you change the return type of the method to `int`, the value will be `0` as expected.

Comment: Thanks Julien! You are right, I should have caught that. Appreciate you pointing it out!